# автоустановка приложений и слежение за состоянием пк

Tags: linux, windows

а работе довольно большой и запущенный парк ПК (1000+). До кучи еще и AD 2008. И надо на эти компьютеры устанавливать нужные приложения, удалять лишние, да еще и следить за парком. Конечно есть саппорт, но хочется им жизнь максимально облегчить.
Использую всус и гпо для обновлений и установки приложений, но все это как то криво косо и отрабатывает дай бог на половине пк. Думаю использовать ансибл или терраформ, но они предназначены для развертывания виртуалок, а не за компами следить.
Вот может посоветуете какое приложение (желательно опен сурс) клиент которого крутился бы на компах, а на сервере я мог бы запускать нужный скрипт и сразу он бы отрабатывал на нужных пк. И работала бы эта схема не только на винде, но и на линукс.

Comment: я когда то писал именно такой софт.  И он все это позволял. Но это был (или ещё есть?) сильно коммерческий софт и не дешевый. Даже под телефоны работало. Но, что бы не считали, что это реклама, писать название компании не буду. Если такой бесплатный софт? не, не видел. Платного? куча, с разными примочками (таймтреккеры, следилки за чатами). Заметил, что большинство такого софта имеет в названии слово endpoint.

Comment: @k сам использовал самописный вариант, но что бы его сделать безопасным надо сильно постараться. Вот и думал найти что нибудь уже написанное.

Comment: иногда мне кажется, что проще взять готовый ботнет и оно будет работать лучше, чем половина существующих решений.

Comment: нпр., saltstack

Comment: `Ansible` отлично ставит виндовые проги, твикает реестр и запускает пошиковские скрипты. Только он работает в режиме `push`.

Comment: SCCM  -мировой стандарт

Comment: https://listoffreeware.com/free-software-deployment-tool-windows/